# Some keys don't work, arrow keys increase brightness and volume on restart

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I restarted my Aspire E-475 (using Ubuntu 18.04) just now and my keyboard's been completely remapped.

Arrow keys are increasing brightness/ volume. And all keys on right-side of my keyboard are doing something else. Not sure what's gone wrong. 
I'm pretty sure my keyboard settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, looks like my Fn key was stuck, and everything else was just due to the Ubuntu shortcuts. This is a common occurrence with the Acer Aspire series, so I'm surprised I couldn't find anything online. 
Hopefully, I can find this post when this inevitably happens to me on my next Acer laptop.